# Construction of an ellipse

Tags: conic-sections, geometric-construction

Is it possible to construct an ellipse with a line, compasses and a pencil? If yes, how and why is the construction correct?

Comment: Constructing an ellipse would require drawing a curve that is neither a line nor a circle. Doing so is not possible with just a compass and straightedge.

Comment: You can, however, find arbitrarily many points on the ellipse and "connect the dots".

Comment: If the line is a piece of string and the compasses can be used to fix two points as foci, then there is a classic construction.

Comment: There are also many constructions that approximate ellipses reasonably well with circular arcs; these are well known to engineers (or used to be before the age of computers ...). Look into *ovals*.

Comment: [This diagram](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1120261/409) shows a way to construct points of an ellipse from two circles. As has been mentioned, you can't draw a "continuous" ellipse this way, but you can construct as many individual points as you like.

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comments, this is not possible. The ellipse consists of a line which is neither a straight line (ruler) nor some arc of a circle (compass). It is however possible to draw an ellipse using two pins, a piece of rope and a pencil.

Pin one end of the rope to the paper and pin the other end on the paper as well, in such a way that the rope is not taut. Then pull the rope taut using the pencil and move the pencil around (while keeping the rope taut) to draw an ellipse.

[image]

$F_1, F_2$ are the foci of the ellipse and the length of the string ($a+b$) is of course constant and equal to the length $PQ$ (the long axis).

Comment: There also is (or used to be) an mechanical-drawing gadget called a *trammel*, it has also appeared as a children’s toy. Draws a very satisfying and mathematically correct ellipse. Accuracy depends on the tightness of the mechanical construction.

Comment: I suppose it works in a similar way, using the fact that (per definition) the distance from any point P to $F_1$ plus the distance from P to $F_2$ is constant for all points on the ellipse.

Comment: [Trammel in action](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hfw0yYur5S4) on Youtube. Trammels are also commonly used to cut elliptical mirrors and windows.

Comment: No, @Dasherman, it’s more like a parametrization of the ellipse $t\mapsto (a\cos t,b\sin t)$. It’s in Wikipedia as “Trammel of Archimedes“.

Comment: I see, interesting stuff. I love how many approaches there are to a problem. And how many of them actually work

Answer (score 2):

You can construct an arbitrary number of points on an ellipse using e.g. [Pascal's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_theorem) (which doesn't even require compasses). If you want the ellipse as a curve, though, not as a set of points, then this is strictly speaking impossible since both ruler and compasses can only draw curves of constant curvature, which the ellipse is not. You can, of course, come arbitrary close.

Answer (score 2):

here is a compass and rule construction of of an ellipse with major axis $a$ and foci at $F_1 = (-ae, 0)$ and $F_2 = (ae, 0)$

here are the construction steps:

(a) pick two points $F_1, F_2.$ draw the line $F_1F_2$

(b) draw a circle with center $F_1$ and radius big enough to contain $F_2$ within it. let the circle cut $F_1F_2$ extended at $A$ so that $F_2$ is between $F_1$ and $A.$

(c) pick any point $Q$ on the circle, draw the perpendicular bisector of $F_2Q$.
  let the bisector cut $F_1Q$ at $P.$

(d) $P$ is on required ellipse. now move the point $Q$ on the circle and get more of the points $P$ corresponding to $Q.$