# Parametrization of the ellipse $\frac {x^2} {p^2} + \frac {y^2} {q^2} = 1$.

Tags: geometry

Consider the ellipse ($p > q > 0$) $$\frac {x^2} {p^2} + \frac {y^2} {q^2} = 1$$. I want to prove that $$\mu(t) = (p \cos(t), q \sin(t))$$ is a parametrization of the ellipse.

I see that $(x/p, y/q)$ must lie on the unit circle. However, I don't see how to formally prove that the "image" of these equations are identical ?

Comment: Isn't $x^2/p^2+y^2/q^2=1$ enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u=\dfrac xp$ and $v=\dfrac yq$.
Then $u^2+v^2=1$.
This means that $(u,v)$ is on the unit circle.

Draw the segment joining $(u,v)$ to $(0,0$) and look at the angle $t$ that it makes with the horizontal axis. Then $u=\cos(t)$ and $v=\sin(t)$.

$~\qquad\qquad$[image]

(image from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle).)

Comment: But why must $x = p \cos(t)$ then ? I don't see this :S

Comment: @Nicolas, see my edited answer.

Comment: Ahh I get it, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : Any general xcoordinate can be expressed as $p \cos \theta$ and then assuming this point lies on ellipse, get the other coordinate of ellipse.

Answer (score 0):

This picture may help you see the appropriate relationships between the trig functions and the ellipse:

[image]