# Ellipse, formula point by angle and angle by point do not match

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

I use to normal function to draw an ellipse (height 250.0, width 150.0).

```
angle = 0.1707           
x = width * Cos(angle)    // x = 147.8196
y = height * Sin(angle)   // y = 42.4706
```

With an angle, you get a point. But when I check this point with
the normal function for "angle between two points", the result
is different

```
angle = Atan2(y, x)    // = 0.2797
```

I don't know what's wrong here ... is there a way to achieve
the same results?

Comment: Presumably you are using *angle* to construct a unit circle and then stretching it by *width* and *height* to get your ellipse.  This stretching changes the actual angle

Comment: The parameterization angle $\theta$ is different from the geometric angle between the points. See ["eccentric angle"](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EccentricAngle.html).

Comment: $\operatorname{Atan2}(x/width, y/height)\;$ should return the same result...

Comment: @RaymondManzoni This is right and easy thank you!! I mixed up x y above so the solution is Atan2(y/height , x/width)

Comment: BTW: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1120261/409) shows a diagram with the geometric meaning of the parameter $\theta$ as it relates to auxiliary circles associated with an ellipse. Clearly, $\angle POE$ (where $E$ is the parameterized point) is almost-never equal to $\theta$. (I'd swear I had an answer that described this situation in full, but I can't find it.)